# Find creation date of a directory in Linux

Tags: linux, directory

I would like to know how to find creation date of a directory in linux.
I tried debugfs stats , but is isn't working for me and is showing following error: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while opening filesystem
stat: Filesystem not open.
Is there any other way?

Comment: maybe use the `stat` command?

Answer (score 1):

**It works for me**

First, you need to get directory inode using

```
$ ls -i <directory_name>
```

After that check Filesystem for the directory

```
$ df -T <directory_name>
```

After use debugfs

```
$ debugfs -R 'stat <inode>' /dev/<Filesystem>
```

**Note:** Please login as root

Answer (score 0):

simply use the `stat` command with the directory name, nothing too complicated.